# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see my external usb audio interface

Tags: usb, sound, 16.04, soundcard

I have the Audient iD14 audio interface, and I was able to get it to work with Ubuntu 14. However, when I did a fresh new install of Ubuntu 16.04, it wouldn't even list it in the sound devices. The only way to play sound is to plug my headphones directly into the desktop computer and use the internal audio (which is inconvenient because the computer isn't close, and I would like to have the higher quality sound from the audio interface.) This might be a bug that I will just have to wait to be fixed, but is there any way to fix it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this same issue, try `sudo apt-get remove fwupd`, see:

https://askubuntu.com/a/766069/538252